# Is there any way to show the summation of area charts value in highcharts without using a line chart? I would like to know other alternative

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Is there any way to show the summation of area charts value in highcharts without using line chart? I would like to know any other alternatives.

Comment: Hi @Thirupathi Govindharaj, Could you explain your problem more precisely? What is the exact result you would like to achieve?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, First of all I apologies for late reply. I have attached an image url https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWbk0.png, In this chart, I have an area chart with five series and the last series is a line chart to show the summation of all the area chart.How to achieve the same functionality without using the line chart to show the summation In area chart? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `area` series with `stacking: 'normal'` and set `lineWidth` and `lineColor` for the series at the top.

```
series: [{
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: 'red',
    ...
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sft7bu8r/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.lineColor